# Do fstab options have to be the same for backup server?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, fstab

I have two small Ubuntu servers in remote locations backing up data to each other.  I'm trying to troubleshoot a problem, and someone suggested my filesystems might be incompatible, and to check fstab entries.  Honestly, I'm a little out of my element with that.

Server 1 has an external USB drive and the entry is:

```
UUID=[the drive's UUID] /mnt/bigdisk    auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Server 2 uses a Synology NAS and the entry is:

```
192.168.30.102:/volume1/bigdisk /mnt/bigdisk      nfs auto,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0
```

I don't really know where these lines came from at this point.  Probably followed some guide years ago.  Do they look OK?  For example, I see the first one has auto as an entry separated by a space while the second includes it in the comma separated list.

I tried reading the MAN page for FSTAB.  Several items aren't described, such as x-gvfs-show and nolock.

In case it helps, the issue I'm trying to troubleshoot is that ownership is not being preserved when backing up the files from Server 2 to Server 1 using rdiff-backup (but preservation is occurring the other way round).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, they don't need to be identical, so long as the target filesystem provides the expected features.

For example, if you are backing up files with xattrs (or the backup process itself relies on xattrs, such as rsync's fake-super) then the target filesystem must of course support xattrs... which no longer needs any fstab options, but used to in the past.

*(Besides that, different filesystems have different options – it's fine to back up from an ext4 disk to an XFS disk, but some ext4-specific options won't make any sense with XFS.)*

So in your case, the expected feature is the ability for root to use `chown` and assign arbitrary owner UIDs to existing files. The problem is that the target filesystem is NFS – and usually, NFS servers operate in "root_squash" mode which makes root completely unprivileged: if the client insists that the operation (e.g. chown) was done by root, the server actually behaves as if it was done by the "nobody" user instead. This means root is not allowed to chown anything.

To avoid this, change the NFS export options on the NAS to use `no_root_squash`, as mentioned [in this forum thread](https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/17/post/75594). Note that this is an export option, *not* a filesystem option on either side.

*(Overall, this issue is not specific to just NFS; many other network filesystems don't provide special treatment for root, as they grant access by account instead of trusting the client-specified UID.)*

Comment: Thanks.  In Synology DSM -> Shared Folder -> bigdisk -> NFS Permissions, Squash is set to "No mapping".  I'm assuming that's the same as no_root_Squash?  I couldn't find "NFS export options".